# Proving Stewart's theorem without trig

Tags: geometry, triangles

Stewart's theorem states that in the triangle shown below,

$$ b^2 m + c^2 n = a (d^2 + mn). $$

[image: Stewart's theorem]

Is there any good way to prove this without using any trigonometry? Every proof I can find uses the Law of Cosines.

Comment: For inner product spaces, the version of Stewart's theorem in this [tweet](https://twitter.com/mathusmassias/status/1707285347963416885), namely ${ \lVert \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \rVert ^2 = \lambda \lVert x \rVert ^2 + (1-\lambda) \lVert y \rVert ^2 - \lambda \cdot (1-\lambda) \lVert x - y \rVert ^2  }$ holds. It can be checked by expanding terms ${ \lVert \alpha x + \beta y \rVert ^2 }$ as ${ \langle \alpha x + \beta y, \alpha x + \beta y \rangle }.$

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it using the Pythagorean theorem. I'll treat the case in which $\angle (a,b)$ and $\angle(a,c)$ are both acute and $m \gt n$ as in your figure.

Draw the height $h$ of the triangle $abc$ and denote the resulting middle segment on $a$ by $x$. Using the Pythagorean theorem one sees

$$\begin{align*}
b^2 &= h^2 + (n+x)^2 \\
c^2 &= h^2 + (m-x)^2 \\
d^2 &= h^2 + x^2
\end{align*}$$

Therefore
$$\begin{align*}
b^2 m &= h^2m + n^2m + 2mnx+x^2m \\
c^2 n &= h^2n + m^2n - 2mnx + x^2n \\
b^2 m + c^2n &= (n+m)(h^2  + mn + x^2) = a(d^2 + mn)
\end{align*}$$
as we wanted.

---

If $\angle(a,c)$ is obtuse, the same idea works: Write
$$b^2 = (m+n+x)^2 + h^2, \qquad c^2 = x^2 + h^2, \qquad d^2 = (m+x)^2 + h^2$$
and calculate similarly.

Symmetry and the consideration of some degenerate cases easily lead to a complete proof of Stewart's theorem from what I've written here.

It would be very nice to have a good pictorial proof that makes the identity similarly obvious as Pythagoras, but so far I couldn't come up with a nice figure that would achieve this.

---

**Added:** [Matthew Stewart](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Stewart.html) (1717–1785) published this theorem as Proposition II on page 2 in his 1746 book *[Some general theorems of considerable use in the higher parts of mathematics](http://www.archive.org/details/somegeneraltheo00stewgoog)* (arxive.org). Unfortunately, Google's scans don't seem to include the figures, but they are easy to reconstruct from the description in the text.

**Update:**(by @brainjam) I've taken the liberty of adding a partial scan of the figures from another [Google scan](https://books.google.ca/books?id=JGxbAAAAQAAJ) -

One case of Stewart's Proposition II reads in the above notation:

$$b^2 + c^2 \frac{n}{m} = an + d^2 \frac{a}{m}$$

and it has the following nice corollary:

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 2d^2 + m^2 + n^2.$$

Here's the title page and the relevant passage (not using trigonometry either). Since Proposition I is used in the proof, I'm including the entire beginning of the text:

[image: Frontispiece]
[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]
[image: Page 3]
[image: Page 4]
[image: Page 5]
[image: Figures]

Comment: @Ben: A complete proof needs to take care of the case when the vertex opposite to $a$ is to the right of $a$, of course, but I'm pretty sure that the elimination process should work in that case, too. It's late here, I leave that to you.

Comment: @Ben: The other case is just as easy. Just call the new segment $x$, so $b^2 = (m+n+x)^2 + h^2$, etc.

Comment: @Ben: I added scans of Stewart's original proof

Comment: A genuinely old document; I note that the letter "s" in the main text is the old-school "s" that eventually became our integral sign. (+1 of course.)

Comment: @J. M. Thanks, of course I noticed it. I read the proof (and quite a bit more in that book). It's very beautiful if sometimes a bit complicated. I didn't know that this in-word/end of word distinction for "s" (as the Greek did) was used in other languages than German in the modern era. By the way, a remnant of the in-word versions is the ß (esszet).

Comment: Oh, nobody writes "Gauß" or "Weierstraß" anymore? ;)

Comment: @J. M. Sure, people do. They still torture young children with the darn letter. Fortunately, I never had to care about this thing because in Switzerland it isn't taught. It is still mandatory, but it got simplified a bit, recently. The only thing which is more complicated is where to put the commas.

Comment: @J.M. Btw. some people still listening to Rush? Good to know!

Comment: @Theo: I have often been panned for my antiquated tastes, but it's always nice to hear I'm not alone... :)

Comment: @J.M. *antiquated?* Thanks a lot! The Tom Sawyer song is **younger** than me!!!

Comment: Aw man, I meant no offense @Theo, sorry. (The song is younger than me as well, but not too much.) I do however get teased a lot for sticking to classics in my neck of the woods...

Comment: @J.M. No worries, none taken! None at all. :) It's pretty close for me too I'm $100000b$ at the moment. After the apology you've got my unrestrained sympathy, transmitted to you from the other end of the world, so all the more effective... :)

Answer (score 3):

Geometric equivalents of the Law of Cosines are already present in Book II of Euclid, in Propositions $12$ and $13$ (the first is the obtuse angle case, the second is the acute angle case).

Here are links to [Proposition $12$, Book II](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookII/propII12.html), and to [Proposition $13$.](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookII/propII13.html)

There is absolutely no trigonometry in Euclid's proofs.

These geometric equivalents of the Law of Cosines can be used in a mechanical way as "drop in" replacements for the Law of Cosines in "standard" proofs of Stewart's Theorem.  What in trigonometric approaches we think of as $2ab\cos\theta$ is, in Euclid, the area of a rectangle that is added to or subtracted from the combined area of two squares.

Comment: What you describe is in fact very close to what Stewart did himself. I hope you like the scans I included in my answer. The book is a gem!

Comment: @Theo Buehler: Yes, Joyce's *Euclid* is beautiful, and the use of colour outstanding.  Indeed I very much like the scans from Stewart. It is important that people be exposed to the real history of mathematics, not just to modern interpretations.  Amazing how many people think that the Pythagorean Theorem is about the square **of** the hypotenuse, when it is actually square **on** the hypotenuse.

Comment: I can't express how much I agree with that!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, see the Wikipedia article [*Stewart's Theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem).  I personally prefer the symmetric formulation of the theorem, because it is easy to remember without any mnemonic trickery:

> Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be points on a directed line $l$ in the Euclidean plane, and $P$ be a point anywhere in the plane. Then
>   $$
> PA^2\cdot BC + PB^2\cdot CA + PC^2\cdot AB + BC\cdot CA\cdot AB = 0~,
> $$
>   where the length of a line segment $XY$ on the line $l$ is positive if the segment has the same direction as the line, and is negative if it has the opposite direction.

**Proof.**  The proof is by straightforward calculation.
Choose a Cartesian coordinate system with the directed line $l$ as the first axis,
and let the points involved have the coordinates $A=(a,0)$, $B=(b,0)$, $C=(c,0)$, $P=(x,y)$. Stewart's identity is essentially just the polynomial identity
$$
(1) \quad (x-a)^2(c-b) + (x-b)^2(a-c) + (x-c)^2(b-a) + (c-b)(a-c)(b-a) = 0~,
$$
which is easily verified. (Go and really do the calculation: it's fun to observe everything cancel out.) Now add to the above identity the obvious identity
$$
y^2(c-b) + y^2(a-c) + y^2(b-a) = 0~,
$$
and you have the full-blown Stewart's theorem. **Done.**

Note that the theorem is true also in partly degenerate situations, where some of the points $A$, $B$, $C$ coincide, or the point $P$ is on the line $l$.
A geometric reasoning has to discuss these degenerate cases separately, while the computational proof smoothly subsumes them in the general case.

**Remark.** The identity $(1)$ is a *generic* polynomial identity, which means that it is an identity in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c,x]$ of polynomials in (formal) variables $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$ with integer coefficients, and therefore instantiates to an identity when the variables are replaced by elements of an arbitrary commutative ring. This observation tells us that Stewart's theorem is valid in the 'Euclidean plane geometry' over any commutative ring, in particular over any field.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your hands on 
M. S. R. Anjaneyulu, Elements of Modern Pure Geometry, Asia Publishing House, New York 1964 (MR0172146 (30 #2372)), it may have what you want. The review, by Coxeter, starts, "This is a nicely written text-book. The work begins with directed line segments, Stewart's theorem, and a metrical definition for the harmonic relation...." and the review never mentions trigonometry.